# PHP XAMPP mail() sent, but not delivered to mailbox

Tags: php, email, xampp, gmail

I have problem with mail() function in PHP. I'm using XAMPP. Here are my configuration files:

***php.ini***

```
[mail function]

SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_from = my_mail@gmail.com
sendmail_path = C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\
```

***sendmail.ini (C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini)***

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
error_logfile = error.log
debug_logfile = debug.log
auth_username = my_mail@gmail.com
auth_password = my_password
force_sender = my_mail@gmail.com
```

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$to= "another_mail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Title";
$messages= "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";

if( mail($to, $subject, $messages) ) {
  echo "Email sent!";
} else {
  echo "Not sent!";
}

?>
```

The program is returning *Email sent!* message, but mail is not delivering to my mailbox. I've already tried changing port in *php.ini* and *sendmail.ini* to 465 and nothing changed.

Do you have any idea?

---

**EDIT**:

I think, I,ve found my this php log. It was in polish (my system default leanguage), so the translation can be not perfect - sorry for that. Here it is:

```
Unable to find description for Event ID 2 from PHP-7.4.6 source. Either the component causing this event is not installed on the local computer or the installation is damaged. You can install or repair the component on your computer.

If the event is from a different computer, you may need to save the display information along with the event.

The following information was attached to the event:

php
mail () on [C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ mail.php: 8]: To: another_mail@gmail.com - Headers: - Subject: Title

A message resource is present, but this message was not found in the message table
```

Do you have any idea now? What's going wrong?

Comment: You will need to debug your system yourself, since we do not have access to your system. Your code only hands over the message to `sendmail` and declares that as "success". But that does not mean that the message actually is sent. That depends on other things too. To find out about that you will need to take a look into your system's log files. That is where `sendmail` will mention if it cannot deliver your message.

Comment: Ok, but where can I find this mail log file? @arkascha

Comment: That depends on your system, obviously. I have no idea what system you are working on. Looks like this is a MS Windows OS (a bit exotic to operate a server on...), so you not find many guides for this... You will have to check your `sendmail` configuration about where it logs to. Or maybe you can find something inside the usual system log facilities MS Windows offers, I think it is called "Event Log" or something, but am I not certain there. That system is a bit unfamiliar to me, sorry.

Comment: @arkascha I've posted this log, do you have an idea now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it! Now it works!

I had to go to **[myaccount.google.com](https://myaccount.google.com) > security** and set  2 step verification, and then generate app password (for xampp).

I did it thanks to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5uCc8Hab-I

Thanks!